# PySpark - Path does not exist when loading local file (image)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am going trough my first steps with `spark` in python using `pyspark` and I am facing several doubts and a failure I could not solved after looking for a working solution. So far I am doing:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext('local')
spark = SparkSession(sc)
```

I dont fully udnerstand the code above. Is it something that has to be always present when starting a pyspark project? Is `SparkContext` set to `local` since I am working locally with my computer and not yet in the cloud?

In any case, when I try to load a local file, in this case an image, I get the following error:

```
path = 'file:///home/guacamole/Training/sprk/myimage.jpg'
image_df = spark.read.format("image").load(path)

AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/home/guacamole/Training/sprk/myimage.jpg;
```

Looking similar questions I see it is pointed out that `file:///` has to be added to specify it is a local file. Not sure what I am missing or doing wrong here.

Comment: you don't need to specify `file:///`. I think that's for databricks. `/home/guacamole/Training/sprk/myimage.jpg` should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write the path with backslashes rather than normal slashes,
the `file:///` shouldn't be there, so just use :
`path = '\\home\\guacamole\\Training\\sprk\\myimage.jpg'`.
If the image is in a different directory just enter the full path but use 2x backslashes.
(in python "\" are used to neutralize the function of/remove the char coming after them so if you write a single backslash that whole path will be a random text, but if you use 2 backslashes the first one isn't gonna show up as its just a neutralizer, and as the second one is neutralized from its function it wont remove the char after it).